# substr function in PHP5

Tags: php

I am developing an application were I need to use the next PHP5 code:

```
<?php

$Hurrengo_Hitza = 'word_3';

$Handiena_MarkID = 0;  
$Handiena_Hitzarentzat = -2;
$Hitza_Index = substr($Hurrengo_Hitza , 5);

    print $Handiena_MarkID . $Hitza_index . $Handiena_Hitzarentzat;
```

The result I am looking for is `0 3 -2` and the result I am getting is `0-2`. Which is the problem?

Comment: try to use english variable name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just a minor case of typo and case sensitivity.

```
print $Handiena_MarkID . $Hitza_index . $Handiena_Hitzarentzat;
```

Notice in that line it says `$Hitza_index` and not `$Hitza_Index`. Since variables in PHP are case-sensitive, you need to change that to `$Hitza_Index`.

Answer (score 0):

Variables in PHP are case-sensitive.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$Hitza_Index = substr($Hurrengo_Hitza, -1);
```

Comment: And yes, agree with what exactly the others answer said. Variables in PHP are case-sensitive. So, pay attention to the line: `print $Handiena_MarkID . $Hitza_Index . $Handiena_Hitzarentzat;`

Answer (score 0):

You have a lowercase i in $Hitza_index when printing, while it's uppercase when assigning.